# Flutter: Showing overlay without context

Tags: flutter

There are some flutter libraries (inbuilt as well as external) that seem to be able to create an `overlay` without taking `context` as a parameter (See this for example: https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast).

I'm creating my own `notification package`, and I'd like to know how I could show a `notification widget` as an `overlay`, without explicitly passing `BuildContext` as a parameter. Does anybody have any idea how libraries like the one above achieve this?

Comment: You could look at the source code of the package to see how they solve this problem

Comment: Could ask the user to inject their context into your toast component

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code, you will see the lib provide two ways to show toasts:

1. Show toasts by plugin, **render by native code without flutter context**.
2. Show toasts by flutter runtime **with flutter context**.